# stream interface for logger, C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I need to implement LoggerStream that does something like this

```
LoggerStream() << "Logged this info " << " my info with value = " << value;
```

I have a class Logger with function info.

```
std::ostringstream msg;
msg << "my info " << " with value = " << value;
logInfo(msg.str());
```

How to write this wrapper LoggerStream() ?

Thanks!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: to simplify usage of the logger

Comment: i mean what code did you write and what problems did you encounter? Currrenlty your question reads like "please gimme the code", but I hope you didnt come here without a specific problem that you need help with, because "gimme the code" is unlikely to happen. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: i have this task and i don't know even where to start. Is LoggerStream a function ?  But what is << for it then ?

Comment: Consider `std::cout` and `std::cerr`. Recall that from the program's point of view, standard output and standard error are file handles

Answer (score 1):

That's a very convoluted use case of logger. You would need to reimplement a lot of operators to facilitate output.  Do not create function class.. create either self-registering class (that is, only one instance for each output target exist, e.g. for each log file) or singleton that works like `ostream`, or maybe is even convertible to `ostream`, then you can use ALL operators<< defined for `ostream`.

Essentially it would be wrapper around std::ostream with conversion operator defined.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: `LoggerStream` needs a constructor, an overload for `<<` and a destructor that flushes some internal stream to whatever stream you want to log to.

Comment: PS: not claiming that this is a high quality answer, but I started to change my habit of writing comments instead of answers and hope the question will be clarified by OP.